# What is the maximum Transaction size in hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I tried to upload an Image into the ledger (converted image to base64 string and passed it as an arg in the transaction ).

When i send an image of size 30 kb it worked fine , But with an 100kb image my transaction failed , stating that the max size is 102400 .

My question is what is the maximum size of the transaction and the maximum size of the Block ?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure max size in your peer configuration under block size. But you may need to configure the grpc Frame size to a bigger value so that peer should accept a message from client. By default grpc frame size is *"4194304"*.

Here is the way we can set frame size using fabric-sdk-java

```
Properties peerProperties = conf.getPeerProperties(peerName);
peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9999999);
```

Comment: But keep im mind that this approach is not recommended, you should save the files outside the blockchain and keep the hashes saved in the ledger

Comment: What is the typical size of a Fabric transaction? Say my payload is just 2 or 3 variables. Eg - Banking chaincode with { Acc_no : int, Action: String, Amount: int }. The action could be deposit/withdraw.

Comment: What is conf property and where to set this property in smart contract?